# How to open .doc file is ms word app in android using intent action?

Tags: android, android-intent, ms-word, doc

I tried to open the .doc file in android app using intent action view its showing 
Error

> try saving file on device and then opening it

It works well in aother app like polaris,wps...etc

Why its not working in ms word android app

IN Manifest.xml

How to fix it?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Please edit your question and provide a [mcve]. That would include the `<provider>` element in your manifest for the `com.ksoft.propreka` authority, along with the actual `ContentProvider` implementation that the `<provider>` element points to.

Comment: ` @Override
    public String getType(Uri uri) {
        return "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
    }`         issue fixed after adding this in provider